# Probability of a dice game

Tags: probability, dice

Here is my question... n players playing a dice game which any of them who trows a 6 the game is over and he wins. They do it 1 by 1 .So what is the probabilty of winning for any 1 of them ?

My calculation about it is like
 $$ P =\left(\dfrac1{6} \right)^{n} $$

Is that right ?

Comment: That's the probability when $n$ players throw $n$ dice and everyone wins. Each one plays in turns, if he wins the game's over(Fun and difficult part).

Comment: Is there a limited number of turns, or may the game go on forever (so long as noone rolls a $6$)?

Comment: The game keeps goin on untill 1 of the n players get 6 in their turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

First round: player 1 wins with probability $\frac{1}{6}$, player 2 with $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$, $\cdots$, player n with $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

Second round: player 1 with $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{6}$, player 2 with $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$, and so on...

The winning probability of each given player equals the sum of his winning probabilities in each round.

Comment: If player one wins, game's up! How do you know about the $n$th player's probability of winning?

Comment: ahh so you say that i have to count the rounts too if n players cant get 6 in their turns. Aha got the message thx.

Comment: Given the information that player one wins, then his winning probability is 1 and others' 0. However we do not have this kind of information a priori.

Comment: Consider a general case rather. If player $k$ wins. The probability of others winning is $0$

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your conclusion. However this says that the conditional probability of others winning given the information that player k wins is 0. I think here we need unconditional probability.

Comment: We do know that the others have 0 probability. The question was acttualy what is the winners probabilty. So if its first player its 1/6 and the rest is (5/6)^n * 1/6

Comment: This solution can be generalised to give an exact probability for each player irrespective of how many rounds there are - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way: let $p_k$ denote the probability of the $k$th player winning. Then $p_k=\frac{5}{6}p_{k-1}$ for $1<k\le n$. Now use $\sum_{k=1}^np_k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $n$ players each with $p=\frac{1}{6}$ chance of winning on their roll.

After 1 round there is a $(\frac{5}{6})^n$ chance that the game has not ended *and* the situation is exactly the same as it was at the start of the game. Therefore we only need to normalise the probabilities over that first round by dividing by $1-(\frac{5}{6})^n$.

Player 1 has a $\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^n}$ chance.

Player 2 has a $\frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^n}$ chance.

In general, Player $k$ has a $(\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^n}$ chance.

So for a 2 player game, Player 1 has $\frac{6}{11}$ and Player 2 has $\frac{5}{11}$.